# Am I using the Lambda Calculus term _combinator_ correctly?

Tags: c#, linq, linqpad, lambda-calculus

I am OOP-heritage C# developer trying hard to respect the theory behind functional programming. In the following code sample below, am I using the Lambda Calculus term *combinator* (in `FuncCombinator`) correctly?

```
<Query Kind="Program" />

public static class FuncExtensions
{
    public static Func<T, bool> And<T>(this Func<T, bool> thisPredicate, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        return a => thisPredicate(a) && predicate(a);
    }

    public static Func<T, bool> AndNot<T>(this Func<T, bool> thisPredicate, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        return a => thisPredicate(a) && !predicate(a);
    }

    public static Func<T, bool> Or<T>(this Func<T, bool> thisPredicate, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        return a => thisPredicate(a) || predicate(a);
    }

    public static Func<T, bool> OrNot<T>(this Func<T, bool> thisPredicate, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        return a => thisPredicate(a) || !predicate(a);
    }
}

public static class FuncCombinator
{
    public static Func<T, bool> Combine<T>(bool @bool = true) { return f => @bool; }
}

void Main()
{
    var data = new[] { 2, 4, 6, 8, 11, 43, 65 };
    var greaterThanFourAndLessThanForty = FuncCombinator.Combine<int>()
        .And<int>(i => i > 4)
        .And<int>(i => i < 40);
    data.Where(greaterThanFourAndLessThanForty).Dump("Greater Than Four and Less Than Forty");

    var notGreaterThanFourAndLessThanForty = FuncCombinator.Combine<int>()
        .AndNot(greaterThanFourAndLessThanForty);
    data.Where(notGreaterThanFourAndLessThanForty).Dump("Not Greater Than Four and Less Than Forty");
}
```

Comment: Instead of `Combine`, you may want to just use `True<T>() => x => true;` and `False<T>() => x => false;`

Comment: Since you mentioned lambda calculus, there combinator is just lambda without free variables, like `x => x `. Not sure how this definition is related to your FuncCombinator class.